# Argument data type text is invalid for argument of len

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I don't understand why there's a such error there (marked in the code below).

I've tried to put this on comment but the error still occurs at line 64. 
I'm using sql server 2005.

Error :

```
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prSwiftGetMessages, Line 64
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.
```

Code :

```
delete from Messages where LOAD_DATE >= @minDate print 'Deleted : ' + convert(varchar, @@ROWCOUNT)

print 'Date MIN = ' + convert(varchar, @minDate,102)

print 'Dropping Indexes.' 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesReference')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesReference 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesLoadDate')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesLoadDate 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesBankTo')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesBankTo 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesBankFrom')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesBankFrom 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesTo')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesTo -- ERROR HERE !! 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesFrom')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesFrom 
if exists (select 'x' from sysindexes where name = 'idxMessagesEnv')
      drop index Messages.idxMessagesEnv print 'Indexes Dropped'
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using the `len` function in that code.

Comment: Your code has several problems, but `len()` is not among them.